# Implementing a tensor product formula

Tags: performance, beginner, c, matrix

I would like to use C to implement the following formula:

$$\mathbf S(u,v)=\sum_{r=i-p}^{i}\sum_{s=j-q}^{j}N_{r,p}(u)N_{s,q}(v)\mathbf P_{r,s}$$

Namely,

$$
\left(N_{i-p,p}(u),\cdots,N_{i,p}(u)\right)_{1\times(p+1)}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{P}_{i-p,j-q} & \cdots & \mathbf{P}_{i-p,j}\\
\vdots& \cdots &\vdots\\
\mathbf{P}_{i,j-q} & \cdots & \mathbf{P}_{i,j}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
N_{j-q,q}(v)\\
\vdots\\
N_{j-q,q}(v)\\
\end{pmatrix}_{(q+1)\times 1}
$$

where,

$$\mathbf P_{i,j}=\{x_{i,j},y_{i,j},z_{i,j}\}$$ or

$$\mathbf P_{i,j}=\{x_{i,j},y_{i,j},z_{i,j}, w_{i,j}\}$$

So the middle matrix is actually a **tensor** with rank 3, like this:

```
{{{1,1,0.09986},{1,2,0.07914},{1,3,0.80686},{1,4,0.68846},{1,5,0.297402}},
 {{2,1,0.12262},{2,2,0.41283},{2,3,0.38565},{2,4,0.05670},{2,5,-0.12276}},
 {{3,1,0.08301},{3,2,0.13181},{3,3,0.36565},{3,4,0.74432},{3,5,-0.62065}},
 {{4,1,0.12755},{4,2,0.06099},{4,3,0.74465},{4,4,0.18402},{4,5,0.336987}},
 {{5,1,0.12346},{5,2,0.97057},{5,3,0.72663},{5,4,0.23481},{5,5,0.968757}}}
```

Here is my algorithm and implementation with C code:

[image: C-like algorithm]

```
void calc_bspline_surf(double *P, double *U, double *V, int p, int q, double u, double v, int const *dims, double *S) {
    double *Nu = (double *) malloc((p + 1)*sizeof(double));
    double *Nv = (double *) malloc((q + 1)*sizeof(double));
    double *temp = (double *) malloc(dims[2]*sizeof(double));
    int m, n, c;
    int i, j;
    int k, l, r;
    int uidx, vidx, idx;
    m = dims[0];
    n = dims[1];
    c = dims[2];
    i = find_span_index(p, U, m - 1, u);
    j = find_span_index(q, V, n - 1, v);
    b_spline_basis(p, U, i, u, Nu);
    b_spline_basis(q, V, j, v, Nv);
    /*main implementation*/
    uidx = i - p;
    for (l = 0; l <= q; l++){
        for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){
            temp[r] = 0.0;
        }
        vidx = j - q + l;
        for (k = 0; k <= p; k++){
            idx = c*n*(uidx + k) + c*vidx;
            for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){
                temp[r] = temp[r] + Nu[k]*P[idx+r];
            }
        }
        for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){
            S[r] = S[r] + Nv[l]*temp[r];
        }
    }
    free(Nu);
    free(Nv);
    free(temp);
}
```

Notes:

- For a tensor `T` with dimensions `{m, n, c}`, which was stored with a flattened vector `V`, we can refer to `T[i][j][k]` with `V[n*c*i + n*j + k - 1]`
- In function `calc_bspline_surf()`, the `Nu`, and `Nv` stores the values of vectors `N(i-p,p),..., N(i,p)` and `N(j-q,q),..., N(j,q)`, respectively.
- `S[0],...,S[c-1]` store the results

The complete file could be download with this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv1awyv6yreh3ye/bspline_test.c?dl=0).

Owing to I am a C newcomer, I think my code is not fast. I'm seeking a more efficient strategy for dealing with this problem.

Comment: Do you have a name for that matrix formula?  Or some better way to characterize it other than "a matrix formula"?

Comment: @syb0rg Maybe call it **tensor product**?

Comment: What aspect of this code do you want reviewed? Or is it just a general review request?

Comment: @chux In fact, I would like to know that : is there more efficient method to implement that tensor product?

Comment: "efficient method" could be taken as execution performance (speed) - which is what I _think_ you want.  "efficient method" could also mean minimal data space, minimal source code, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Readability & Maintainability

- Right now your code is a bit hard to read.  A way to *greatly* help this would be to use better variable names.

  [image]
- Put the variable declarations to separate lines *and* initialize them to some value **at the same time**. From *Code Complete, 2d Edition*, p. 759:

  > With statements on their own lines, the code reads from top to bottom,
  >   instead of top to bottom and left to right. When you’re looking for a
  >   specific line of code, your eye should be able to follow the left
  >   margin of the code. It shouldn’t have to dip into each and every line
  >   just because a single line might contain two statements.
- You should declare your `for` loops as such:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  ```

  Note that this was introduced in the C99 standard.  There is no reason you should not be using this standard in your code.

## Design

- Group your variables in `struct`s to make them more maintainable, a
  good hint that you should be doing this is when you are passing in
  ***9*** parameters to your function.
- Return the output vector; it makes your function easier to use. 
  You'll have to allocate the space in your method and free it
  elsewhere.  This also eliminates the potential bug discussed below.
- [Don't cast `malloc()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1937270)
- Right now you are using this loop to zero out `temp` (or at least part of it)

  ```
  for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){
      temp[r] = 0.0;
  }
  ```

  The [original algorithm](https://books.google.com/books?id=CkeqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=NURBS%20A3.5&source=bl&ots=d4oxbI2WMi&sig=D7dev2RHunRSaVyAR7trkx3O8JM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN9bWrnvbNAhVINj4KHe8TDVYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=NURBS%20A3.5&f=false) doesn't implement this in a separate loop, and I don't recommend you do either.  It's a loop in the code you don't need.
- These lines:

  ```
  temp[r] = temp[r] + Nu[k]*P[idx+r];
  S[r] = S[r] + Nv[l]*temp[r];
  ```

  Can be shortened to:

  ```
  temp[r] += Nu[k]*P[idx+r];
  S[r] += Nv[l]*temp[r];
  ```
- Set those pointers you `free()`ed to `NULL` right after.  This prevents us from trying to access the data afterwards, which will result in undefined and usually catastrophic behavior.

## Bug

- Right now you are relying on the passed in values already stored in `S[r]` when you add `Nv[l]*temp[r]` to them.  In the original NURBS A3.5 algorithm, they are 0'ed out right before their use.  You could overwrite all these values to 0 with a `memset()` in our function and continue as is. However, overwriting something the user passes when we could've started from scratch is usually not expected behavior.

  Create the array at the top of the function like you do with the other arrays, using `calloc()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot:)  I will refactor it according to your suggestions. About the `S[r]`, I have initialized it to 0 with for-loop in previous function.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I know you did, I looked at your full implementation.  It is still a bug IMO, and is very likely to result in unexpected results.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Don't forget to up-vote and (if you deem) accept! ;)

Comment: Using `calloc()` is practical for assigning `0.0`.  C does not require a bit pattern of zero interpreted as a FP to be 0.0 - so pedantically, `for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){
    temp[r] = 0.0;
}` is more portable.

Comment: @chux Performance wise however, `calloc()` would be an improvement, no?

Comment: At best, it is minor.  Any significant speed improved certainly must be in the inner most `for()` loop. `for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){` or with a whole new approach.

Comment: Further `for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){
    temp[r] = 0.0;
}` is done `q+1` times.  `calloc()` only helps on the first loop.  Suggest deleting that suggestion as it is functionally incorrect.

Comment: @chux According to [the original algorithm that the OP is using](https://books.google.com/books?id=CkeqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=NURBS+A3.5&source=bl&ots=d4oxbI2WMi&sig=D7dev2RHunRSaVyAR7trkx3O8JM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN9bWrnvbNAhVINj4KHe8TDVYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=NURBS%20A3.5&f=false), he shouldn't have a separate loop for it.  I misunderstood his intentions initially, I'll make an edit quick.

Answer (score 5):

To improve execution performance, focus on the inner loop

```
void calc_bspline_surf(double *P, double *U, double *V, 
  int p, int q, double u, double v, int const *dims, double *S) {
    ...
        vidx = j - q + l;
        for (k = 0; k <= p; k++){
            idx = c*n*(uidx + k) + c*vidx;
            for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){
                temp[r] = temp[r] + Nu[k]*P[idx+r];
            }
        }
```

Help the compiler use its optimizations.  By using `const`, the compiler can know  referenced data should/not will not be changed and optimize accordingly.

```
void calc_bspline_surf(const double *P, const double *U, const double *V, 
  int p, int q, double u, double v, int const *dims, double *S) {
```

By using `restrict`, which effectively says the referenced data will not change by using the other pointers, again, more optimizations can occur.

```
void calc_bspline_surf(
  const double * restrict P, const double * restrict U, const double * restrict V, 
  int p, int q, double u, double v, 
  int const *restrict  dims, double *restrict  S) {
```

For a minor help, the inner loop *may* benefit a bit with re-order code.  Profile different ways.

```
            // Choose 1:
            // simplify end-of-loop test 
            for (r = c-1; r >= 0; r--){ 
            // or
            for (r = c; r-- > 0; ){ 
            // or
            for (r = 0; r < c; r++){ 
            // or original
            for (r = 0; r <= c - 1; r++){ 
                // Choose 1:
                // This _may_ make for better code.
                temp[r] += Nu[k]*P[idx+r];
                // A good compile will generate the same code with this source
                temp[r] = temp[r] + Nu[k]*P[idx+r];
            }
```

Comment: Hm, I haven't really seen much use of `restrict` in the wild.  Good thing to note for future reviews, +1!